# os.path.isfile returning false

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been browsing around and can't quite come up with a reason why the `os.path.isfile()` constantly returns false in this case.

```
if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(rootDir, file)):
     print("hit")
else:
     print(os.path.join(rootDir, file))
     print("else")
```

Both variables made by `os.path.join(rootDir, file)` are formatted as: `./rootDir/file1` and `./rootDir/file2` when printed in the else block.

You see, each file should be compared in the rootDir from a subdirectory before being moved into the rootDir; however, it is only catching the else statement.  If the file exists, which one does as './rootDir/file1' and one './rootDir/sub/file2', then the result should be one hit and one else being printed.

Since one is indeed in a file in that directory (as shown by the print(os.path.join(rootDir, file)) statement), I don't understand why both are hitting the else (false).

PS. Both files are .pptx files just incase that matters

Comment: I think there is problem in your rootDir definition. What actually in your rootDir Variable?

Comment: I feel very sheepish right now.  You were indeed right, I was up one subdirectory more than I originally intended thus it wasn't, of course, finding the files.  Thanks for the pointer and question to make me check.